# How to unit test void methods whos result is calling a webclient?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Assuming I've something like this:

```
public void sendNotification(String uuid) {
   List<MyData> dataList = myDataRepository.findAllById(uuid);
   NotificationDto dto = new NotificationDto();
   for (MyData data : dataList) {
     // transform and append to dto
   }

   webclient.send(dto);
}
```

How can I unit test that given `myDataRepository` returns a list of xyz the right content is sent? Is the only way to extract the dto creation in a public method just for unit test purposes?

Comment: You mock the webclient and verify that the mock is called with the correct values.

Comment: you can mock a webclient as a mockbean to replace webclient in code.

Comment: Can you add the transform to DTO logic as well to the question